# django - initial data in test

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

Here are two functions in my UserTestCase(APITestCase) class. The capital variables are constant. Is there any way to test api instead of creating too many constants and dumd data like "data" in test_create_user function? Which is best practice of testing in term of initial data in django?

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = APIClient()
    # create staff
    self.admin = User.objects.create_user(email=ADMIN, password=PASSWORD)
    self.admin.is_staff = True
    self.admin.is_active = True
    self.admin.save()

    self.user = User.objects.create_user(email=ADMIN, password=PASSWORD)
    self.user.is_active = True
    self.user.save()

def test_create_user(self):

    login = self.client.login(email=ADMIN, password=PASSWORD)
    self.assertTrue(login)

    data = {
         'email': EMAIL,
         'password': PASSWORD,
         'first_name': FIRSTNAME,
         'last_name': LASTNAME,
         'nationality': NATIONALITY,
         'is_active': True,
    }

    # configure urls
    url = reverse('apiv2:user-list')
    # url1 = reverse('apiv2:user-detail', args=[self.user.id])

    # create new user
    user = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(user.status_code, 201)

    # login after create
    login = self.client.login(email=string_normalize(
        self.data.email),
        password=PASSWORD
    )
    self.assertTrue(login)

    self.client.logout()
```

Comment: What you are looking for is called "fixtures". Look for that word in the docs for the test framework you are using.

Comment: i don't need a dump data of real db. I just need some fields so that I can test a PUT api, for example. @HåkenLid

Comment: Yeah. It's still called fixture data, whether you use a database dump or create it in a setup function.

Comment: @HåkenLid so how can I use fixtures? Can u give me a example?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using some mock library such as [Model Mommy](http://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to create your fixtures easily based on the Django Model declaration. And it is most likely that you will load initial data in the setUp method of your tests.